Pull back in quotient stacks
I am started learning about stacks. I am reading Alper's notes Stacks and Moduli. I am getting difficulty to verify the following is a cartesian square. Can someone give some hint how to start? For checking the universal property do I need to define the 2-morphism by hand or they will come from some other property?
Here $U$ is a scheme. $G$ is an algebraic group acting on $U$. $[U/G]$ is the quentient stack. $P$ is a principal $G$-bundle over $T$. $f$ is a $G$-equivarient map.



Thanks in advance.

The construction of $\Psi$ in Lemma 2.4.21 gives you a hint already: there needs to be a choice of pullback in associating to to the bundle the map $T\to [U/G]$. Definition 2.4.15 of $[U/G]$ will also help. The trick is to unwind all the data at every point (that is, given a 2-commutative square as required as input by the 2-universal property, what does this mean in terms of the definition of $[U/G]$?)

@DavidRoberts Sorry, I did not get it can you elaborate little more?

To put it another way: you could show directly that the stack associated to $P$ is equivalent to the pullback construction 2.4.33, rather than verify the universal property. You need to use how $T\to [U/G]$ is defined, and that is in terms of some pullback, which will help. This map is $\Psi_T(P\to T)\colon T \to [U/G]$, where $\Psi=\Psi_T\colon U/G \to \mathrm{Mor}(T,[U/G])$ is constructed as in Lemma 2.4.21: $$\Psi_T(P\to T)\colon (T' \stackrel{f}{\to} T)\mapsto (f^*P \to T').$$ Also, Example 2.4.26 gives the definition of $U\to [U/G]$, and you need to unwind this, too.

If you are trying to verify the universal property, rather than construct an equivalence to $T\times_{[U/G]}U$, then given morphisms $T' \to T$ and $T'\to U$ making the diagram 2-commute (with invertible 2-arrow $a$), you need to unwind what this data is. Again using 2-Yoneda, $a$ corresponds to an arrow in $U/G$, which ultimately is an isomorphism of $G$-bundles commuting with the equivariant maps to $U$. In the case that $T'=P$, one can work out what $a$ "should be" in the universal case.
